# Автокомплит с динамической подгрузкой на Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Имеется back-end на **Go** и front-end на **Vue** (+Vuetify). Необходимо сделать автокомплит для адресов по типу dadata.

Я новичок в JS и ищу что-то подходящее с минимумом переделок. Готового решения не нашел, но нашел подобный вопрос и вроде как даже ответ к нему на гитхабе - https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/835#issuecomment-320526536

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    v-model="city"
    label="Select"
    :items="cities"
    @input.native="loadStates"
    autocomplete
  ></v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
import debounce from 'debounce'
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      city: null,
      cities: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadStates: debounce((event) => {
      if (event.target.value.length > 2) {
        Vue.http.post('http://localhost:1324/api/v1/cities', {name: event.target.value}).then(response => {
          var citiesList = response.body
          if (citiesList) {
            citiesList.forEach(el => {
              this.cities.push(el.name)
            })
          }
        }, response => {
          console.log(response.body.message)
        })
      }
    }, 200)
  }
}
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что внутри метода loadStates, не могу писать в this.cities. Получаю ошибку:
*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined*.

По этой же причине делаю запросы через Vue.http, вместо this.$http.
Не подскажите в чем трабл?

Comment: как Вы определяете, что запросы не идут?

Comment: С помощью вкладки Network в Chrome

Comment: метод debounce отрабатывает? в условие заходит?

Comment: Проблема была в том, что axios не хотел дружить с vue-resource. Остановился на последнем. Теперь новая проблема (исправил вопрос).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что проблема заключается в области видимости `this`. Вы можете сохранить ссылку `this` в переменную и получать данные через нее.

```js
..
methods: {
  loadStates: function () {
    debounce((function (self, event) {
        if (event.target.value.length > 2) {
            self.$http.post('http://localhost:1324/api/v1/cities', {name: event.target.value}).then(response => {
              var citiesList = response.body
              if (citiesList) {
                citiesList.forEach(el => {
                  self.cities.push(el.name)
                })
              }
            }, response => {
              console.log(response.body.message)
            })
          }
    })(this, event), 200)
  }
}
..
```

Comment: Теоритически понял, практически когда использую ваш код вообще ничего не происходит. Запросы не уходят, ошибок в консоли нет.

Comment: @Paulo немного поэкспериментировал и изменил код, на этот раз должно работать

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь. Сейчас все работает как надо.